# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n}{n^2+k^2}=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

> Show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n}{n^2+k^2}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Using real analysis techniques.

Comment: Riemann integral sound familiar?

Answer (score 9):

**Hint**: It's a Riemann sum.
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1 + (k/n)^2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Riemann summation
 factor n^2 from n^2+k^2 and simplify then go on

Comment: You can't write limit of something if you don't know if this limit exist...and it's a waste of time :)

Answer (score 0):

No rigourous, but leads to the solution:

$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{1+\left(\frac kn\right)^2}\approx\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n  1 - (k/n)^2 + (k/n)^4 - (k/n)^6\dots  
\approx\frac1n(n-\frac{n^3}{3n^2}+\frac{n^5}{5n^4}-\frac{n^7}{7n^6}\dots)
,$$
by keeping the first terms of the Faulhaber sums.

$$1-\frac13+\frac15-\frac17...=\frac\pi4$$
is Gregory's series.