# Find a Riemann Integral given the limit of a sum

Tags: limits, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

I need to find a Riemann Integral corresponding to this limit

$$ \lim_{n->inf}\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{n}{n^2+r^2} $$

I tried equating the fraction to a $\frac{b-a}{n}f(x_r)$ where $x_r=a+r(\frac{b-a}n)$ but I can't seem to be able to find f(x) at all.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546298/show-that-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-1n-fracnn2k2-frac-pi4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Rerwite the fraction by multiplying both the numerator and denominator by $1/n^2$.  This gives
$$\frac1n\frac{1}{(r/n)^2+1}.$$

It should be a lot easier to recognize this as a Riemann sum.